# Problems with WIFI

Tags: settings, release-juno, wifi

I just installed elementary on my Windows PC and I have problems with wireless network : the WIFI networks are not detected.

[image: network settings]
You can see the wireless connexion is enabled, but it says it is disabled...
The available networks are detected in ~the 5 first minutes of uptime, and then... nothing.

```
me@mypc:~$ ip a | grep wlp
3: wlp3s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:9f:38:55:af:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here you can see that wlp3s0 is "DOWN".
Can you help me to use my wireless network ?

PS: My version of elementary is 5.0, and all packages are up-to-date.
My PC is an ASUS Vivobook 14 X405UA

The command `sudo lshw -sanitize -C network` returns

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: enp2s0
       version: 15
       numéro de série: [REMOVED]
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources: irq:16 portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:ef104000-ef104fff mémoire:ef100000-ef103fff
  *-generic
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: Illegal Vendor ID
       fabriquant: Illegal Vendor ID
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: wlp3s0
       version: ff
       numéro de série: [REMOVED]
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 66MHz
       fonctionnalités: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8822be driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources: irq:132 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:ef000000-ef00ffff
```

And `lspci` returns these informations about my wireless interface :

`03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822 (rev ff)`.

`modinfo r8822be | grep parm` returns

```
parm:           debug_level:int
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
parm:           dma64:Set to 1 to use DMA 64 (default 0)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
```

.

Comment: Can you provide the machine brand and model, the wifi adapter brand and model if you know how to get it, and the output of the commands: `sudo lshw -sanitize -C network` | `lspci`

Comment: Ok, I added them to my question.

Comment: Run this please: `modinfo r8822be | grep parm`. And next time don't crop outputs, I got the info I needed but in the future don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the parameters is `aspm`, when you run `$ modinfo r8822be | grep parm`

Try, in a terminal window, running:

`$ sudo modprobe -r r8822be`

`$ sudo modprobe r8822be aspm=0`

---

If it works to make it permanent just run:

`$ echo "options r8822be aspm=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/50-r8822be.conf`

*The next time you reboot you won't have to execute any command*

ref:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364383&page=4&p=13748692#post13748692

https://askubuntu.com/a/1085786/890782

Comment: I tried your solution but when I ran this all wireless settings disappeared from the desktop.

Comment: Yet you still "crop" the result by not providing them. I can't help you if you don't help me to help you. Simple as that. PS: To rollback just reboot, if you made the change permanent even if it didn't worked you clearly didn't read what I wrote. The solution for the later (in this specific case) is remove the file and reboot. To remove the file just run: `sudo rm -fr /etc/modprobe.d/50-r8822be.conf`. Good Luck

Comment: Sorry, after testing your solution I forgot to post the output. I read your whole post and I did not make it persistent. I'll post the output tomorrow.

Comment: I just added `modinfo r8822be | grep parm` output to my question

Comment: Is my question abandoned ? I really need to use WiFi on eOS.